# Integration of Oracle JET with APEX

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-jet

I am trying to integrate Oracle JET with Oracle APEX, I tried to find information about integration. I found some blog posts for older version of APEX and Oracle JET - I can't find a way to download oraclejet.zip file and “Oracle JavaScript Extension Toolkit : Base Distribution”?

I tried to install files using npm, but there I can't find files which I should upload to apex static files.
Or this files: https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/jet400/jet/developer/GUID-219A636B-0D0B-4A78-975B-0528497A82DD.htm#JETDG-GUID-219A636B-0D0B-4A78-975B-0528497A82DD

I want to add JET diagrams to Oracle APEX and other components too.

Answer (score 1):

Oracle JET has been part of the standard APEX installation for the past couple of years. The most recent release, [APEX 21.1 contains Oracle JET 10.0.0](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/application-express/21.1/htmrn/index.html#HTMRN-GUID-175489FB-CC24-40F6-89EF-A4A7AAFD7770). There are plenty of Oracle JET components that can be used declaratively by APEX, but you should still be able to reference the library through standard JavaScript if you so choose.

Comment: Sorry for late comment :( What about version 20.2?

Comment: APEX 20.2 contains Oracle JET 9.1: https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/application-express/20.2/htmrn/index.html#HTMRN-GUID-A5C02F23-1A64-4F2C-A18B-09612D995B2A